# How far does the range of magic go?

Tags: disgaea-5

I've been training my Magic based characters and, once reaching Skill Level 21, the distance of the Spell from the caster is 6 panels.

I want to know how far the range goes, for both Healing Magic and Elemental Spells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/835980-disgaea-5-alliance-of-vengeance/72871085), it appears that spell range is capped at 10.

> Two ways to increase the range of a spell.
>
> - Goto the Skill Shop, and spend Mana to increase it's range (not the option to increase it's power). Increasing it's range also gives you more panels to cast with.
> - Use the spell in battle to increase it's level. Use the Cheatshop and max out the Skill EXP slider, and equip a Mentor Innocent (if you have one). If your Mentor is high enough, you can potentially lv99 a spell (or any other skill) in about 4 or 6 uses.
>
> All of those boosts will give upto +18 range, but the game softcaps at 10 range.

In addition to that range, you can also unlock AoE versions of your spells, which can add a little bit of range on top of that (but will cost more SP to use).

Comment: I'm confused by the term "softcap" here. If there's no way to get more than 10 tiles of range on spells, despite meeting requirements that would otherwise unlock 18 tiles of range, then that really sounds like a hardcap instead.

Comment: @Ellesedil I think softcap is a misnomer in this instance, but I left the quote the way it was originally worded. What you said is correct.